# How can I launch Cerebro using Super key on it's own

Tags: shortcut-keys, 19.04

I would like to launch [Cerebro](https://cerebroapp.com/) using only <kbd>Super</kbd> key. I am running Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

Just change config.json
`/home/<yourUserName>/.config/Cerebro/config.json`
and change hotkey value
`eg. "hotkey": "Alt+Space"`
and restart.